# How to show that $g$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**

Let $f:[0,1]\to[\alpha,\beta]$ be a continuous function such that $f([0,1])=[\alpha,\beta]$. Define another function $g(x)$ by the following rules,

- If $\alpha<0<\beta$ then define, $$g(x)\begin{cases}=\dfrac{f(x)}{\lfloor \alpha\rfloor} & \alpha\le f(x)< 0\\[5mm]= 0 & f(x)=0 \\[5mm]=\dfrac{f(x)}{\lceil \beta\rceil} & \beta\ge f(x)> 0\end{cases}$$
- If $\alpha,\beta<0$ then define, $$g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{\lfloor \alpha\rfloor}$$
- If $\alpha\ge0$ and $\beta>1$ then define, $$g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{\lceil \beta\rceil}$$

Examine the continuity of $g$.

**My Proof**

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence converging to $c\in[\alpha,\beta]$.

1. Let $f(c)<0$. Since $f$ is continuous we can say that for all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all sufficiently large $n$, $$\left\lvert f(x_n)-f(c)\right\rvert<\varepsilon\implies \left\lvert\dfrac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{\lfloor \alpha\rfloor}\right\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon} {\left\lvert \lfloor \alpha\rfloor\right\rvert}\implies\left\lvert g(x_n)-g(c)\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$
2. Let $f(c)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous we can say that for all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all sufficiently large $n$, $$\left\lvert f(x_n)-f(c)\right\rvert<\varepsilon\implies \left\lvert\dfrac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{\lceil \beta\rceil}\right\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon} {\left\lvert \lceil \beta\rceil\right\rvert}\implies\left\lvert g(x_n)-g(c)\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$
3. Let $f(c)=0$. Since $f$ is continuous we can say that for all $\varepsilon>0$ and for all sufficiently large $n$, $$\left\lvert f(x_n)\right\rvert<\varepsilon\implies \left(\left\lvert\dfrac{f(x_n)}{\lceil \beta\rceil}\right\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\left\lvert \lceil \beta\rceil\right\rvert}\right)\land \left(\left\lvert\dfrac{f(x_n)}{\lfloor \alpha\rfloor}\right\rvert<\dfrac{\varepsilon} {\left\lvert \lfloor \alpha\rfloor\right\rvert}\right)\implies\left\lvert g(x_n)\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$

---

But I think that there is something missing in my proof, especially in the third part. My questions are the following,

> - Is my proof correct ?
> - Is there another shorter method to prove this ?

$\color{red}{\text{Those who wish to post an answer please include in your answer an answer of my first question.}}$

Comment: Why are you using convergence when trying to prove continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, using the definition of sequence-continity,  though I'd like you to be a bit more elaborate in the third part (especially, don't just drop the case $x_n=0$). It may also be more adequate to work with the $\epsilon,\delta$-definition of continuity.

A faster way may be to note that $g(x)=h(g(x))$ for a nice continuous function of the form $h(x)=c_1\cdot x+c_2\cdot|x|$.

As a sidenote: Of the three definitions for $g$, only the first need to be considered. The other two can be summarized as special cases of the first.